# What are some SQL Server 05/08 security measures that can be put in place to prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

I have a java web application. I have taken measures to prevent SQL injection on the code side as far as using stored procedures and regular expressions. However, Java is very easily decompiled and can be modified to inject SQL commands directly to the SQL Server, making my use of stored procedures and regular expressions worthless.

Therefore, my question is what are some restrictions that I can put in place on the SQL server side to prevent malicious commands from being executed? Currently, I have an administrative SQL user accessing the database which is NOT what I want. I want to be able to prevent commands such as the following:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_executesql N'Exec sp_configure ''show advanced option'', ''1'''
EXEC master.dbo.sp_executesql N'RECONFIGURE'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_executesql N'Exec sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', ''1'''
EXEC master.dbo.sp_executesql N'RECONFIGURE'
```

I think what I have in place will prevent most script kiddies and hackers from injecting, but I am still worried about the hackers who are smart enough to decompile the code and modify it accordingly. (The Java app is unfortunately cached for performance reasons which allows for this to be done if you know what you are doing)

Comment: Is this an applet? An applet must not have direct access to the server's database. Or does the application run solely on the server? Then you do not need to worry about decompilation, because the user interacts with the application only via HTTP and does not have access to your class files..

Comment: It is a Java Web Start Application.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx

"To execute sp_configure with both parameters to change a configuration option or to run the RECONFIGURE statement, you must be granted the ALTER SETTINGS server-level permission. The ALTER SETTINGS permission is implicitly held by the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles."

Your SQL account(s) for application access should not have this level of permission. Not sure if that's what you are indicating, but if so, I would take those rights away ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

eek - you really don't want an applet or web start app connecting directly to your DB server!

If that is really a requirement, the first thing you'll want to do is ensure that the connection to the database is encrypted (otherwise your user, when running your app in an internet cafe, is broadcasting credentials all over the place): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx

Rather than starting from "everything" (admin user) and restricting things, you'll want to work the other way around: determine what the user really needs access to, and give them access to that only. For simple data access, this may be as simple as making the user part of the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` groups, or as complex as explicitly granting the appropriate permission on each of the objects the user (or, hopefully, role)  needs access to.